# How to make one branch based on another?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I performed certain operations on my repo. (It was actually an attempt to sync svn branches with git, but let's pretend that they are unknown for the sake of the question — just trying to keep it minimal, as SO guidelines advise). After that, I ended up with a branch `broken_branch` that is not based on anything. Just a single commit without any parents.

```
$ git lg
* 5757abc - (HEAD, origin/branches/broken_branch, broken_branch) ~ Some broken branch commit message (58 minutes ago) <AuthorName>
```

However, I **know** that this commit should be based on other commit with hash, let's say, `abc1234` from `master` branch. So, I try to do a logical thing, rebase:

```
$ git rebase abc1234
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: ~ Some broken branch commit message
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:829: trailing whitespace.
  userData:
<stdin>:839: trailing whitespace.
  userData:
<stdin>:849: trailing whitespace.
  userData:
<stdin>:859: trailing whitespace.
  userData:
<stdin>:869: trailing whitespace.
  userData:
warning: squelched 204361 whitespace errors
warning: 204366 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Path/To/File/Class.cs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Path/To/File/Class.cs
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 ~ Some broken branch commit message
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /Path/To/Project/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Where `Path/To/File/Class.cs` is the file that was modified in the single commit of `broken_branch`. Actually, there were like 20 files modified, and for every single one of them I got the same message.

(I'm replaced all strings in this question in order not to accidentally leak anything, but I made an effort to make everything consistent).

So, I have these questions:

1. Was my decision to use `git rebase` to solve this issue correct? Or should I have used something else?
2. Why do these errors appear? I'm positive that the `broken_branch` was initially created (in svn, but let's keep svn out of the scope of the question) on this particular commit.
3. How can I resolve this rebase to give me desired result?

Comment: Note for potential edits: I didn't tag it with `svn` because I tried to keep the context of the question minimal. I only mention `svn` to explain how did I reach this state (because someone will ask me about it otherwise), but it should be irrelevant for the question's sake.

Comment: Also, I think that this question has a really bad title right now, but I can't think of a better one. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: I'd go for a cherry pick of the broken banch commit on a new branch created from the "known" father. Then delete the broken branch.

Comment: @BigMike tried it; got `error: could not apply 5757abc... ~ Some broken branch commit message` with same merge conflicts

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want your git repo to look like this:

```
    abc1234
    |
    5757abc'
```

where the contents of 5757abc' match exactly 5757abc and is a child of abc1234?  If so, then you can do this:

```
# Create test_branch pointing to commit 5757abc
git checkout -b test_branch 5757abc

# Reset test_branch to point to abc1234, but do not change the index 
# or working copy (these still contain everything in 5757abc)
git reset --soft abc1234

# Commit your changes
git commit -m "My New Commit"
```

Reference: https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html

This will modify git history as you want.

You can also modify `<repo>/.git/refs/remotes/origin/branches/broken_branch` so `origin/branches/broken_branch` points to this new commit.

However, I do not know if git-svn will work properly after this.  Be sure to backup before attempting this!